# lUbuntu: File manager no longer shows other partitions

Tags: lubuntu, file-manager, pcmanfm

I hope I don't end up kicking myself for an obvious answer here, but in lubuntu 17.04(zesty) I cannot find the "other places"(as in the other partitions on my system, like Windows) anywhere in the file manager.. It's perplexing, because the option used to be there in the sidebar(called something like "other places"). Currently though, it's not there, and I don't know how to get it back. I can still see the other partitions with Gparted and mount them if I wish.. but I want to browse them with the GUI too.. anyone got the answer?

Comment: What  filemanager do you use. Controll if /etc/fstab has some entries for the Partition you miss in it.

Comment: @Bahamut The file manager is pcmanfm. I didn't understand the second part of your comment, but everything in /etc/fstab appears to be in order..

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab`  please.

Comment: @Bahamut It doesn't have the Windows partition in /etc/fstab if that's what you're looking for... but I'm pretty sure it never did, and that it shouldn't. Only the partitions pertinent to lUbuntu are there(They match up uuid-wise with Gparted).. those being the root, home and swap partitions.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to simply revert to the original settings where the file manager listed all partitions without having to mount them. I assume if I list them all in /etc/fstab, they will be mounted automatically on boot.. Can't find anything helpful with Google..

Comment: In `$HOME/.config/pcmanfm/default/pcmanfm.conf`  section `[volume]
mount_on_startup=0
mount_removable=0
autorun=0` means not mount anithing on boot, nor mount usb-sticks/DVD automatically nor autorun

Comment: @Bahamut Thanks. I checked the file, all of them are currently set to 1, but it still isn't working as it should. I have figured out a workaround, but it doesn't really answer the question.